# Booting to Windows USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, windows

Now I have Installed Linux as a primary operating system but now I need windows for some applications that wine can't run,I have a 32 GB flash drive I have installed windows 7 on it but it can't boot on windows I used to use EASYBCD to be able to boot to a windows VHD on USB but on Ubuntu I'm stuck and can't do any thing,Is there is a way to install windows 7/10 on USB without VHD to boot normally by selecting the flash drive from the boot menu and if there isn't how do I make my computer boot to the VHD on the USB without harming my Ubuntu system ?

Sorry for the Bad English and thanks in advance .

Comment: Note I Used a Program called wintousb on a windows machine to install windows on the USB .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the USB with your Windows OS is plugged in run this:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Grub will scan all the attached drives for OS installations and add them to the boot menu.

Now your Windows USB installation will appear in the boot menu when you start your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Proceedure:
Obtain 64 or 128GB USB3 flash drive.
Use mkusb to create a persistent flash drive with 1% persistence.
Safely remove and replug flash drive.
Copy existing virtual machine image, (.vdi), to the "usbdata" partition on the flash drive.
Reboot into the USB
Connect to internet.
In Software & Updates, check "Software restricted by ..., etc.", then select "Updates" and ensure the machine will not will not automatically download or install updates.
In Software Center install VirtualBox,
From www.virtualbox.org/wiki/downloads download the extension pack.
Install the extension pack using VBox.
Run VBox and select New, when you get to Hard disk, select "Use an existing..." and choose the image in usbdata.

Results:
So far the drive is working in every computer I try, but very, very slowly in computers without USB3 and/or less than 4GB RAM.
In a computer with lots of RAM some things almost seem faster, like orbiting complex rendered solids in AutoCAD.
AutoCAD 2013 & 2016, SolidWorks, Cosmos FEA, Staad, Autoplant, Rhino and SketchUp all work
Hilti Profis required a new serial number, and CAESAR II and CADWorx required reinstallation of hardware locks.
Have had no luck connecting to a VPN.

Comment: If the answer to this question is exactly the same as another answer you wrote on another question, and answers the same problem, then you should flag this question as a duplicate of the other one, rather than copy-paste answers as is.

Comment: The questions do not appear as duplicates to me, and no one else has marked them as duplicates. One question involves Windows XP and the newer one involves Windows 7/10. Methods that worked for XP (Nigine method), do not work for 7/10. The method I proposed works for both, please explain why I should not post it for both.